# Drupal 8, cannot get node JSON when logged in

Tags: rest, drupal-8

I cannot access the JSON version of a node when logged in, anonymous access no problem. When logged in including Administrator, the end point returns a 403. Updated to Drupal 8.2.1. The requesting page generated from a Module, same host.

Example request: /node/16?_format=json

Comment: Found the problem. The REST_UI module had an incompatibility with Drupal 8.2.1. The dev release of REST_UI works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The REST_UI module had an incompatibility with Drupal 8.2.1. The dev release of REST_UI works correctly.